# Utilizar variável com endereço do site no HTML - Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um site em angular, só que estou tendo dificuldades em utilizar a variável *baseurl*, que contém o caminho base do site, em algumas coisas como links eu consigo utilizar, mas dentro de um *background-imagem* ou em um *ng-click*, por exemplo, ele não funciona.

> Como tem que ser feito para conseguir utilizar a variável para esses
>   fins?

Estou criando essa variável no meu *Constants.js* e chamando ela no meu *controller.js* da seguinte forma:

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope, API, $location) {
            $scope.baseurl = API.url;
            $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (next, current) {
                $scope.url_atual = $location.url();
            });
        });
```

O Constants.js está da seguinte forma:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .constant('API', {
        url: 'http://192.168.110.4/cliente_cliente/em_desenvolvimento/front/bernardo/'
    }); })();
```

Um local que funciona é nos links:

```
<a href="{{baseurl}}#/noticias/interna/#disqus">
```

Um local que não funciona é:

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="disqus" src="{{baseurl}}app/template/img/icone_face_home.png">
```

Também gostaria de colocar dentro de tags script, como baixo, mas não estou conseguindo:

```
var image = {{baseurl}}app/template/img/icone_mapa.png";
```

E dentro de um campo css:

```
<div class="img_principal_noticia_home" style="background-image: url({{baseurl}}app/template/img/img_baner.jpg)"></div>
```

E dentro de um ng-click, também não consegui(rrsrsrsrs):

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.facebook('{{baseurl}}#/noticias/interna')">
```

Comment: Cria uma variável global.

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo Constant.JS?

Comment: o meu constants está assim:
(function() {
    'use strict';
    
    angular
        .module('app')
        .constant('API', {
            url: 'http://192.168.110.4/cliente_cliente/em_desenvolvimento/front/bernardo/'
        });
})();

Pelo oque eu sei, essa variável é global.

Comment: Se você consegue usar em algumas áreas mas não em outras, o caminho relativo é que deve ser o problema. Como está sendo definido em seu html? Coloque exemplos de onde o problema acontece.

Comment: Olá, CelsomTrindade, adicionei exemplos de funcionamento na pergunta

Comment: @BernardoKowacic tente usar da seguinte maneira `ng-src="{{baseurl}}app/....`

Comment: Olá @CelsomTrindade, eu consegui utilizar dessa forma para atualizar imagens que estão nas tags <img>. Uma outra dúvida, como que eu posso fazer para utilizar essa mesma variável em um background-image e dentro de tags script na página (api do google maps)? Irei postar na pergunta, se você puder responder agradeço

Comment: Olha.. Eu não consigo ver motivo para o seu código não funcionar. Se você inspecionar o elemento através do console do chrome, por exemplo, quando utiliza o backgroun dimage, como está o link do style? E se você abrir ele, ele está com um caminho válido e img válida? No ng-click, ao clicar, o que acontece? você consegue algum console de erro informando que o problema é de fato a url?

Comment: Olá, eu consigo utilizar os mesmos utilizando o link direto, mas não consigo da forma como postei.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, poste o seu comenário que vc falou pra mim usar o ng-src (comentário 6) pra mim marcar como correta. Eu consegui resolver o problema que falei hoje simplesmente removendo o baseurl e funcionou igual. Obrigado por ajudar :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema de usar a seguinte definição em uma imagem:

```
<img src="{{meuValor}}" />
```

É que o HTML irá renderizar antes que o Angular possa aplicar o valor correto de `meuValor` e inserir a url correspondente, ou seja, o html irá buscar com uma imagem que possua o caminho `{{meuValor}}` e não o valor propriamente dito do scope `$scope.meuValor`.

Para resolver esse problema foi criado a diretiva `ngSrc`, [mais informações aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc), que faz com que a renderização da imagem ocorra somente após o Angular ter recebido e passado o valor para a `view`.

Ela deve ser usada assim:

```
<img ng-src="{{meuValor}} />
```

---

Quanto aos demais casos, não vejo o por que de não funcionarem do modo como você configurou. Talvez seja algum outro fator que esteja interferindo.

Comment: Complementando a resposta, para caso mais alguém tenha esse problema, no script e no campo css eu resolvi apenas tirando o baseurl, e colocando o caminho a partir do local do arquivo html

Comment: Isso acontece por que naturalmente o caminho parte da raiz. =)

Comment: o velho problema e a maldita chateação do Angular JS é basicamente essa. KKKK (a ordem dos tratores...)